# Darkflow is installed and imported perfectly. But TFNet is not importing from darkflow.net.build

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo, darkflow

Darkflow library is installed succesfully but when it is imported it gives 'ImportError'. When 'darkflow' is imported it gives no error. But when 'TFNet' is imported from 'darkflow.net.build' then it gives 'ImportError: No module named 'darkflow.net''

Installed darkflow successfully and imported it.

```
from darkflow.net.build import TFNet
```

Expected result : TFNet imported

Actual result: ImportError: No module named 'darkflow.net'

Link to the image for error message - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fuwJtAL1pVehd80oa_EglgQRMin_0Q0O

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and fixed installing protobuf==3.5.2